# ejb-jar.xml: ejb-client.jar or ejb-module.jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, ejb-3.1

Sometimes, configurations or declarations need to be done in the EJB-deployment descriptor, the ejb-jar.xml file.

When there is no ejb-client jar-file, ejb-jar.xml is located in the META-INF of the module:

```
Module-root:
   ---> META-INF
        - ejb-jar.xml
        - ...
```

but if a ejb-jar client gets added, where will the ejb-jar.xml be located? In the META-INF of the client:

```
Module-root:
   ---> META-INF
        - // here nothing
        - ...

ejb-client-Root:
   ---> META-INF
        - ejb-jar.xml // here something
        - ...
```

or will the EJB-Module keep the ejb-jar.file as usual?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ejb-jar.xml` should always go in the EJB module JAR, colocated with the bean implementation (`<ejb-class/>`) .class files.  It's possible to have a separate EJB module that is *also* a client, in which case you might have two ejb-jar.xml: one in the "service" JAR and one in the "client" jar.

Comment: None other than the EJB specification; this is just the way EJBs (and EE in general) work.  If it adds any credibility, I have 8 years of EE experience, and 4 years of experience developing an EJB container.